# How can i get file permissions using office365 rest api?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I can access one drive for business using the office365 files rest api however there doesn't seem to be any way to get file permissions or to set file permissions. Is this just not part of the api? If so is there another api that can be used to access file permissions for files in one drive for business?